# I want to add a custom Header to a CSV file that I get from exportCSV of react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

[image]

I want to add a custom Header to a CSV file that I get from exportCSV of react-bootstrap-table2-toolkit

Documentation: https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Export%20CSV&selectedStory=Basic%20Export%20CSV&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

I want to have this while exporting.

Heading

Header
Columns

Could not find a prop to add a heading in case of csv export.